# Where is the mistake in my counter-example to the statement? (sequences of functions, uniform convergence)

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

Statement: 
Let $f,f_n:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and for all $x\in[a,b]$ let $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x) = f(x)$. 
If $f$ and  all $f_n$ are continuous, then $f_n$ converges uniformly against $f$.

Counter example is supposed to be the function
$$f_n( x) ≔ \begin{cases}
g(n·x) &, 0<x<\frac 1 n\\
0 &, \text{else}
 \end{cases}$$

Where $g(x)≔ 8·x^4 - 16·x^3 + 8·x^2$  .

Here is a plot of it for $n$ increasing:

[image]

With this function, all requirements of the statement should be fullfilled:

We have $f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = 0$, so $f$ is continuous.

Further, all $f_n$ are continuous, as $\lim_{x\to 0} f_n(x) = 0 = \lim_{x\to \frac 1 n} f_n(x) $.

However, $f_n$ doesn't converge uniformly against $f$, as for $\epsilon = \frac 1 2$, no matter how high we choose $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $f_n(\frac 1 {2n}) = \frac 1 2$.

Now, I've found two text books claiming the statement to be true, so somewhere I've got to have made an error in my reasoning. I can't find it though: Where is it?

---

Both text books are German (and rather old), the statement is however as faithful translated as possible. 
First is: Landers Rogge, Nichtstandardanalysis, page 132, exercise 1 (from 1994). 
Second is (cited from wikipedia): F. Hausdorff: Grundzüge der Mengenlehre. 1914, Chelsea Publishing Co., New York 1949, Kap. IX, § 4

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$ for the counterexample?

Comment: You are absolutely correct (there is no mistake to be found). Which textbooks are claiming such a thing to be true?

Comment: @AdrianKeister Just big enough, e.g. [-1,2].

Comment: $f_n({1 \over 2n})$ is a non zero constant, hence the convergence cannot be uniform. The only question is what textbook?

Comment: I think your counterexample is correct, the statement is false. Maybe with some extra technical conditions the assertion can be saved. Those textbooks are probably sloppy.

Comment: Perhaps it is required that the sequence $(f_n)_n$ is monotone: [Dini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem)

Comment: Maybe the authors meant it as a counterexample to a plausable claim?

Comment: @mechanodroid That's the solution given in the book - a one-liner saying "use Dini". As it seems though it's actually not me this time, and there's really a piece of information missing.

Comment: I don't see that statement in Hausdorff's book. It's easy to misread II. in chapter IX §4 in this way, which says "Sind alle $f_n(x)$ in $a$ stetig, so ist $f(x)$ in $a$ stetig dann und nur dann, wenn $a$ ein Punkt uniformer Konvergenz ist." However, the term "uniforme Konvergenz" used by Hausdorff is different from (strictly weaker than) uniform convergence (= gleichmäßige Konvergenz). It was an unfortunate choice of term. Hausdorff was aware of its problematic status (to some extent at least).

Comment: In footnote 1 of §4, he writes "Der obige Sprachgebrauch kollidiert übrigens mit dem französischen usw., wo uniform = gleichmäßig ist." [Roughly: The above terminology collides with the French etc., where uniform is "gleichmäßig".]

Comment: On a different note, how is a book from 1994 "rather old"?

Comment: @DanielFischer Well, it means even if there are mistakes, no one has bothered to publish any new edition since 24 years. That's quite a while if you ask me

Comment: For a new edition with corrections, two things are necessary. First, the authors must have been made aware of the mistake, which may not have happened. Second, there must be enough demand for the book, that the publisher expects profit from a new edition. Which is easier in mainstream topics.

Comment: A simpler example: Let $f_n(x) =0$ for $x\not\in [0,2/n]$. For $x\in [0,1/n]$ let $f_n(x)=nx.$  For $x\in [1/n,2/n]$ let $f_n(x)= 2-nx.$

Answer (score 2):

Theorem 7.9 in Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* states the following:

> Suppose $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x) \qquad (x\in E).$$
>   Put $$M_n=\sup_{x\in E}|f_n(x)-f(x)|.$$
>   Then $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $E$ if and only if $M_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$

You can see that for your counterexample, $M_n\not\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Also note the "if and only if".